# Codeigniter form validation - forms value always disappeared

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I'm making a form input in codeigniter with validation. The form validation work fine (if all form are empty), but if i give the value only in 1 or 2 form (there is an empty form) then click the submit(save) button, the value in form always disappeared.

My **Controller-function Save**

```
function save($is_update=0) {

        $data['nik']            = $this->input->post('nik', true);
        $data['nmdepan']        = $this->input->post('nmdepan', true);
        $data['nmlengkap']      = $this->input->post('nmlengkap', true);
        $data['username']       = $this->input->post('username', true);
        $data['password']       = $this->input->post('password', true);
        $data['leveluserid']    = $this->input->post('leveluserid', true);
        $data['jabid']          = $this->input->post('jabid', true);

        $this->_set_rules();
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
            if($is_update==0) {
                if($this->M_menu_user->insert($data))
                    redirect('master/user/C_menu_user');
            } else {
                $id = $this->input->post('id');
                if($this->M_menu_user->update_by_id($data, $id))
                    redirect('master/user/C_menu_user');
            }
        }
    }
```

**Controller-function _set_rules**

```
function _set_rules() {
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
            $session_data            = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
            $data['username']        = $session_data['username'];
            $data['password']        = $session_data['password'];
            $data['jabid']           = $session_data['jabid'];
            $data['leveluserid']     = $session_data['leveluserid'];

            $LevelUser  = $session_data['leveluserid'];
            $username   = $session_data['username'];

            $menus = $this->M_menu->menus($LevelUser);
            $data2 = array('menus' => $menus);

            $this->load->library('form_validation');


            $this->form_validation->set_rules('nik','NIK','required|max_length[10]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('nmdepan','Nama Depan','required|max_length[30]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('nmlengkap','Nama Lengkap','required|max_length[30]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required|max_length[15]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|max_length[30]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('leveluserid','Level ID User','required|max_length[10]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('jabid','ID Jabatan','required|max_length[10]');

            $this->form_validation->set_message('required', '%s <font color="red"><strong>Harus Diisi.</strong></font>');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                $this->data['is_update'] = 0;
                $this->load->view('master/user/V_menu_form_user', array_merge($data, $data2,$this->data));
            } else {
                $this->data['is_update'] = 0;
                $this->load->view('master/user/V_menu_form_user', array_merge($data, $data2,$this->data));

            }
        } else {

                redirect('C_login', 'refresh');
        }       
    }
```

Here is my **view**

```
<?php
  $this->load->view('template/head');
?>

<!--custom css-->
<!-- iCheck -->
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/AdminLTE-2.0.5/plugins/iCheck/flat/blue.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<?php
  $this->load->view('template/topbar');
  $this->load->view('template/sidebar');
?>


<!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">
<?php  

    if(!empty($query)) {
        $row = $query->row_array();
    } else {

        $row['userid']      = '';
        $row['nik']     = '';
        $row['nmdepan']     = '';
        $row['nmlengkap']   = '';
        $row['username']    = '';
        $row['password']    = '';
        $row['leveluserid']     = '';
        $row['jabid']       = '';
    }

    echo "<div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-12'>
                <div class='box box-primary'>
                    <div class='box-header'>
                        <h3 class='box-title'>FORM USER</h3>
                    </div>                

                        <div class='box-body'>";

                            echo form_open('master/user/C_menu_user/save/'.$is_update);

                            echo form_hidden('id',$row['userid']);

                            echo "<div class='row'>
                                    <div class='col-lg-12'>
                                        <div class='form-group'>";
                                        echo "<label class='col-sm-2 control-label'>NIK</label>
                                              <label class='col-sm-1 control-label'>:</label>
                                                <div class='col-sm-3'>".form_input('nik',$row['nik'],"maxlength='10' class=form-control").form_error('nik'). "</div>";
                                    echo "</div>
                                </div>
                            </div> <br>";

                            echo "<div class='row'>
                                    <div class='col-lg-12'>
                                        <div class='form-group'>";
                                        echo "<label class='col-sm-2 control-label'>Nama Depan</label>
                                              <label class='col-sm-1 control-label'>:</label>
                                                <div class='col-sm-3'>".form_input('nmdepan',$row['nmdepan'],"maxlength='30' class=form-control").form_error('nmdepan'). "</div>";
                                    echo "</div>
                                </div>
                            </div> <br>";

                            echo "<div class='row'>
                                    <div class='col-lg-12'>
                                        <div class='form-group'>";
                                        echo "<label class='col-sm-2 control-label'>Nama Lengkap</label>
                                              <label class='col-sm-1 control-label'>:</label>
                                                <div class='col-sm-3'>".form_input('nmlengkap',$row['nmlengkap'],"maxlength='30' class=form-control").form_error('nmlengkap'). "</div>";
                                    echo "</div>
                                </div>
                            </div> <br>";

                            echo "<div class='row'>
                                    <div class='col-lg-12'>
                                        <div class='form-group'>";
                                        echo "<label class='col-sm-2 control-label'>Username</label>
                                              <label class='col-sm-1 control-label'>:</label>
                                                <div class='col-sm-3'>".form_input('username',$row['username'],"maxlength='15' class=form-control").form_error('username'). "</div>";
                                    echo "</div>
                                </div>
                            </div> <br>";

                            echo "<div class='row'>
                                    <div class='col-lg-12'>
                                        <div class='form-group'>";
                                        echo "<label class='col-sm-2 control-label'>Password</label>
                                              <label class='col-sm-1 control-label'>:</label>
                                                <div class='col-sm-3'>".form_input('password',$row['password'],"maxlength='30' class=form-control").form_error('password'). "</div>";
                                    echo "</div>
                                </div>
                            </div> <br>";

                            echo "<div class='row'>
                                    <div class='col-lg-12'>
                                        <div class='form-group'>";
                                        echo "<label class='col-sm-2 control-label'>Level ID User</label>
                                              <label class='col-sm-1 control-label'>:</label>
                                                <div class='col-sm-3'>".form_input('leveluserid',$row['leveluserid'],"maxlength='10' class=form-control").form_error('leveluserid'). "</div>";
                                    echo "</div>
                                </div>
                            </div> <br>";

                            echo "<div class='row'>
                                    <div class='col-lg-12'>
                                        <div class='form-group'>";
                                        echo "<label class='col-sm-2 control-label'>ID Jabatan</label>
                                              <label class='col-sm-1 control-label'>:</label>
                                                <div class='col-sm-3'>".form_input('jabid',$row['jabid'],"maxlength='10' class=form-control").form_error('jabid'). "</div>";
                                    echo "</div>
                                </div>
                            </div> <br>";

                            echo form_submit('btn_save','Simpan',"class='btn btn-primary'");

                            echo "<a href=".site_url('master/user/C_menu_user')." class='btn btn-success'>Kembali</a>";


                           echo form_close();
                        echo "</div>

                </div>
            </div>
          </div>";  

?>

</section><!-- /.content -->
<?php
$this->load->view('template/js');
?>

<!--custom js -->
<!-- Sparkline -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/AdminLTE-2.0.5/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js') ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<?php
$this->load->view('template/foot');
?>
```

look at this pictures, i've filled in 3 form.
[image]

Then i click button **"Simpan"**, the form value will be disappear. *(Simpan = Save/Submit and Kembali = Back/Cancel*). So i need to start again fill the forms. [image]

The validation work fine if all form are empty.
[image]

How to keep the value stay in form ? did i make a wrong form validation ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add value as a second para

```
$value= '$this->input->post('form name')'
```

Also why are you loading your views in your view? you should use a controller? and you should not really save your password into your session.

Example of using forms in Codeigniter are

```
form_input([$data = ''[, $value = ''[, $extra = '']])
Parameters: 
$data (array) – Field attributes data
$value (string) – Field value
$extra (mixed) – Extra attributes to be added to the tag either as an array or a literal string
Returns:    
An HTML text input field tag
```

I personally would use an array tho

```
$data = array(
        'name'          => 'username',
        'id'            => 'username',
        'value'         => 'johndoe',
        'maxlength'     => '100',
        'size'          => '50',
        'style'         => 'width:50%'
);

echo form_input($data,  $value= '$this->input->post('form name')' );
```

Takea look at this website https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: did you mean like this:


`<div class='col-sm-3'>".form_input('username',$row['username'],"maxlength='10' class=form-control value=".set_value('username')."").form_error('username'). "</div>";`

Comment: Hmm, i'm new in codeigniter, so i just try the sample that i found on internet. But thanks for your advice, i'll change it.


`<div class='col-sm-3'>".form_input('username',$row['username'],"maxlength='10' class=form-control value=".$this->input->post('username')."").form_error('username'). "</div>";`


didn't work, the value still disappear.

Comment: Take a look at this url.......https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: i eddited my post take a look @Billadsys

Answer (score 0):

You need to include - set_value('name'); - so the value gets set after submit. When the form returns with errors it will repopulate the input fields where you have set the value.

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#set_value